# (python) SyntaxError: invalid syntax in def function

Tags: python

```
  File "stats0.py", line 40
    def median(numbers):
      ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

```
def median(numbers):
    numbers.sort()
    size = len(numbers)
    midPos = size/2
    if size%2==0:
        median = (numbers[midPos]+numbers[midPos-1])/2.0
    else:
        median = numbers[midPos]
    return median
```

I keep getting this error. I have tried commenting it out but each 'def' has an error. I also looked at each previous questions regarding this error. As far as my understanding, indentation is correct. Please help, this is the first time I have received such an error. (was following a book's code)

Comment: What is before the section you included? The error is there.

Comment: Odds favor an unclosed set of delimiters; usually parens, but braces and brackets (anything that would allow a statement to continue to the next line) work too.

Comment: Side note: You get this function [for free](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.median) with Python 3.4+.  Also, your function does not work on the empty list, though it's debatable whether the empty list has a median at all.

Comment: above this median function is other functions and below is main.

Answer (score 4):

The error would be before the definition of the function. Are there any codes defined before your function. I am able to get the output for the above program. 
The executable code is given below for your reference.

```
def median(numbers):
    numbers.sort()
    size = len(numbers)
    midPos = size/2
    if size%2==0:
        median = (numbers[midPos]+numbers[midPos-1])/2.0
    else:
        median = numbers[midPos]
    return median


if __name__ == "__main__":

    numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    print median(numbers)

Output Console:

5.5

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: still having problems, have code the same, all functions in same format and above the main function. the error still points at the def saying invalid. each time a change is made its saved and execute in terminal.

Comment: Can you share your code - the functions above the median. Or what you are trying to execute